# How to get restaurant menus from Locu API

Tags: android, web-services

I have looked at several APIs for acquiring restaurant menu for a particular location and determined that [Locu](https://dev.locu.com/) API works best for me.

I was trying the basic example listed on locu website:

```
curl -X POST https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search/ -d '{"fields":["name","menu_items","location","categories","description"],"menu_item_queries":[{"price":{"$lt":6},"name":"burrito"}],"venue_queries":[{"location":{"locality":"San Francisco"}}],"api_key":"MY_API_KEY"}'
```

Where, MY_API_KEY is the API_KEY that I received when I signed up.
As long as I include "menu_items" parameter, I keep getting the response:

```
{"status": "error", "http_status": 400, "error": "The requested \"menu_items\" field is either invalid or your account does not have permissions to access it."}
```

I did not come across any documentation regarding what I need to do in order to get the permissions for querying "menu_items". If anyone could point me in the right direction, I will really appreciate that.

I have already gone through some relatively old questions on here and they did not address this particular issue.

Also, there doesn't seem to be a tag for Locu api here. I am going to try and tag the question with some generic tags. Please excuse me for that.

Comment: Sounds like a question you should post their support department.

Comment: I contacted them on twitter. It looked like they've been answering developer queries promptly there. Unfortunately, it wasn't the case for me. :(

Comment: I should also mention that I contacted their official support on their website too.

Comment: Hi @swap_1712, I wonder if you've found the solution to this problem. I'm having the same issue too when I try to query `media` to Locu's API

Comment: I gave up after a couple of emails to their support, since I never heard back. Unfortunately, I have not found as good of an alternate solution. Some research led me to the rumors that companies like Google are relying on Locu for the restaurant menus. Not sure how much of that is true. If it is though, it's no surprise that I didn't get any response. You know.. bigger fish to fry and all of that..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I've found that the solution is to request the "menus" field in a venue search. The API will return the "menu_items" as sub-objects of the menus.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientGet {


public static void main(String[] args) {

  try{
      String result;
      URL url = new URL("https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=" +apiKey);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);} 
   }           
    conn.disconnect();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }
 }
}`
```